# Add animated interval slide to carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this carousel that slides on clicking the 'Next' & 'Previous' buttons but when I try to add an auto slide on intervals it's not working.

If there are any suggestions it will be helpful.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carousel-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
  var total = $('.carousel-item').length;
  var current = 0;
  
  $('#moveRight').on('click', function() {
    var next = current;
    current = current + 1;
    setSlide(next, current);
  });
  
  $('#moveLeft').on('click', function() {
    var prev = current;
    current = current - 1;
    setSlide(prev, current);
  });

  function setSlide(prev, next) {
    var slide = current;
    
    if (next > total - 1) {
      slide = 0;
      current = 0;
    }
    
    if (next < 0) {
      slide = total - 1;
      current = total - 1;
    }

    $('.carousel-item').eq(prev).removeClass('active');
    $('.carousel-item').eq(slide).addClass('active');
    
    setTimeout(function() {
    }, 800);

    console.log('current ' + current);
    console.log('prev ' + prev);
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.6s all linear;
}

.carousel-item__info {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  order: 1;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  width: 40%;
}

.carousel-item__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  order: 2;
  align-self: flex-end;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__subtitle {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  color: #7E7E7E;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__title {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__description {
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.carousel-item--1 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/991012/pexels-photo-991012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}

.carousel-item--2 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/921294/pexels-photo-921294.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--3 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/92733/pexels-photo-92733.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--4 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1008732/pexels-photo-1008732.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--5 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1029614/pexels-photo-1029614.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}

.carousel-item__container {}

.carousel-item__btn {
  width: 35%;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  width: 35%;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}

.carousel__nav span {}

.carousel__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #5d5d5d;
}

.carousel__arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
  color: #282828;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


/* .carousel__arrow:nth-child(1):after {
    content:'';
    right: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    height: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
} */

.active {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}

.active .carousel-item__subtitle,
.active .carousel-item__title,
.active .carousel-item__description,
.active .carousel-item__btn {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible;
}

.active .carousel-item__image {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel__nav">
  <span id="moveLeft" class="carousel__arrow">
    <svg class="carousel__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
    </svg>
   Previous
  </span>
  <span id="moveRight" class="carousel__arrow">
    Next 
    <svg class="carousel__icon"  width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
      </svg>       
  </span>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--1">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The grand moment </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Le tour</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the tour</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--2">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The big window </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Minimal window</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Clear Glass Window With Brown and White Wooden Frame iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--3">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Tropical palms </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Palms</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the palms</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--4">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Beach </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">The beach </h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the beach</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--5">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The white building </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">White building</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `current` between functions. It's already available to all your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your code to make autoplay work:

```
function playSlider() {
    if (current == $('.carousel-item').length) {
      current = 0
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      let next = current;
      current += 1;
      setSlide(next, current);
      playSlider();
    }, 3000)
  }

  playSlider();
```

**Explanation:**

The function `playSlider()` is called upon load and a timeout will begin right after the defined dutation is met then it will call your specified function to change the slide, and call the function again and will check the condition checking whether the `current` gets to the last index and then make the `current` value equal to `0` and begin the loop again.

**Note:** You can change the value of the timeout to make it either slower or faster. Currently `3000` is equal to `3s`

## Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carousel-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
  var total = $('.carousel-item').length;
  var current = 0;

  $('#moveRight').on('click', function() {
    var next = current;
    current += 1;
    setSlide(next, current);
  });

  $('#moveLeft').on('click', function() {
    var prev = current;
    current -= 1;
    setSlide(prev, current);
  });

  function playSlider() {
    if (current == $('.carousel-item').length) {
      current = 0
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      let next = current;
      current += 1;
      setSlide(next, current);
      playSlider();
    }, 3000)
  }

  playSlider();

  function setSlide(prev, next) {
    var slide = current;

    if (next > total - 1) {
      slide = 0;
      current = 0;
    }

    if (next < 0) {
      slide = total - 1;
      current = total - 1;
    }
    $('.carousel-item').eq(prev).removeClass('active');
    $('.carousel-item').eq(slide).addClass('active');

    setTimeout(function() {}, 800);

    console.log('current ' + current);
    console.log('prev ' + prev);
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.6s all linear;
}

.carousel-item__info {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  order: 1;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  width: 40%;
}

.carousel-item__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  order: 2;
  align-self: flex-end;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__subtitle {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  color: #7E7E7E;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__title {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item__description {
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.carousel-item--1 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/991012/pexels-photo-991012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}

.carousel-item--2 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/921294/pexels-photo-921294.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--3 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/92733/pexels-photo-92733.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--4 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1008732/pexels-photo-1008732.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}

.carousel-item--5 .carousel-item__image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1029614/pexels-photo-1029614.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
}

.carousel-item__container {}

.carousel-item__btn {
  width: 35%;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  width: 35%;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}

.carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}

.carousel__nav span {}

.carousel__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #5d5d5d;
}

.carousel__arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
  color: #282828;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


/* .carousel__arrow:nth-child(1):after {
    content:'';
    right: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    height: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
} */

.active {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}

.active .carousel-item__subtitle,
.active .carousel-item__title,
.active .carousel-item__description,
.active .carousel-item__btn {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible;
}

.active .carousel-item__image {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel__nav">
  <span id="moveLeft" class="carousel__arrow">
    <svg class="carousel__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
    </svg>
   Previous
  </span>
  <span id="moveRight" class="carousel__arrow">
    Next 
    <svg class="carousel__icon"  width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
      </svg>       
  </span>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--1">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The grand moment </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Le tour</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the tour</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--2">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The big window </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Minimal window</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Clear Glass Window With Brown and White Wooden Frame iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--3">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Tropical palms </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">Palms</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the palms</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--4">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">Beach </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">The beach </h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Explore the beach</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item--5">
  <div class="carousel-item__image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item__info">
    <div class="carousel-item__container">
      <h2 class="carousel-item__subtitle">The white building </h2>
      <h1 class="carousel-item__title">White building</h1>
      <p class="carousel-item__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      <a href="#" class="carousel-item__btn">Read the article</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```